# File format for fields enclosed with backspace in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, file-format

I have a column whose value is like :

```
'BS1234BS'  (BS  stands for backspace)
```

that is backspace character in the extremes, currently I am using this file_format:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT ABC
    FIELD_DELIMITER = '\u001B'
    ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = 'NONE'
    TRIM_SPACE = TRUE
     NULL_IF = ('<NULL>')
     EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = FALSE;
```

getting this error on adding FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY as '0x08'

SQL compilation error: invalid value ['0x08'] for parameter 'FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY'

what changes should I make, so that it will accept the columns with backspace

Answer (score 0):

That parameter is limited to the characters it can use:

> FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = 'character' | NONE Use Data loading and
> unloading
>
> Definition Character used to enclose strings. Value can be NONE,
> single quote character ('), or double quote character ("). To use the
> single quote character, use the octal or hex representation (0x27) or
> the double single-quoted escape ('').

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html

You can process it externally to change them into a supported character. You'd also need to escape whatever you use for the optional enclosure character, such as \" if you use double quotes.

If your rows aren't wider than 16MB and you'd prefer to handle that inside Snowflake, you could write the CSV to a landing table with a single column defined as string. You could then replace the backspace characters with something else and split the single string into an array to insert into individual columns.